# Hide/show file upload section depending on save state of document in model driven Power App

Tags: powerapps-modeldriven

Finishing build a model-driven Power App. The records have a file upload control where files are shared in Sharepoint.

The user cannot add files until the document is saved in model-driven apps.

I have written code to hide the upload section when the document is new. I want display a message "You must first save the document before you can upload files" when the document is new, and hide it when it is not.

I made a new section on which I put the text above in the label of a file section, with nothing in the section. Just want to display the label.

But when the section (and the label should appear), it does not. If I put some control or something in the section, then the section will appear.

So I thought just put some static text in the section and put in my message in that. Cannot find any way to put static text in the se action.

There must be some standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to find a solution.

I had to add a HTML Web Resource with simple text that said you had to save the record before you could add files. The point being, there must be something in the item you want to be visible that has content and is visible, or it will not show.